# Runge-Kutta Integration on C

Tags: c, function, pointers, runge-kutta

So my code works, it's just that for some reason, my code always runs both if statements(both y equations, no matter which number I enter for the first fprintf question).  Also, the t,y columns are always much longer than the t,y2 columns (EDIT i.e. if I enter funt=1,t0=0,t1=10,inity=1,dt=0.1, my t,y columns have 100 rows and my t,yexact columns have 10 rows).  Furthermore, the t columns of the t,y part have all zeros for the first if statement (y equation) and all of one number for the second if statement(y equation).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double rk4(double(*f)(double,double),double,double,double);
double user_fun_1(double,double);
double user_fun_2(double,double);

int main (void) {
  int funct;
  double *y,t,y2;
  double t0,t1,dt,inity,C;
  int i,n;
  fprintf(stdout, "Which function do you wish to integrate?\n(1)f(t,y)=t\n(2)f(t,y)=-y\n");
  fscanf(stdin,"%d",&funct);
  fprintf(stdout,"What is the initial time?\n");
  fscanf(stdin,"%lf",&t0);
  fprintf(stdout,"What is the final time?\n");
  fscanf(stdin,"%lf",&t1);
  fprintf(stdout,"What is the initial value of y?\n");
  fscanf(stdin,"%lf",&inity);
  fprintf(stdout,"what is the step size?\n");
  fscanf(stdin,"%lf",&dt);
  if (dt>(t1-t0)){
    printf("The stepsize has to be less than or equal to the total time\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;}
  n = 1 + (t1-t0)/dt;
  y = (double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  if (funct=1){
    C=inity-(t0*t0*0.5);
    printf("%s%25s\n","t","y");
    for (y[0]=inity,i=1;i<n;i++){
      y[i]=rk4(user_fun_1,dt,t0 + dt * (i-1),y[i-1]);
      printf("%lf%25lf\n",t,y[i]);}
    printf("%s%25s\n","t","y exact");
    for(i=0;i<n;i+=t1){
      t=t0+dt*i;
      y2=(t*t*0.5) + C;
      printf("%lf%25lf\n",t,y2);}}

    if (funct=2){
      C=inity/(exp(-t0));
      printf("%s%25s\n","t","y");
      for(y[0]=inity,i=1;i<n;i++){
        y[i]=rk4(user_fun_2,dt,t0+dt*(i-1),y[i-1]);
        printf("%lf%25lf\n",t,y[i]);}
        printf("%s%25s\n","t","y exact");
      for(i=t0;i<n;i+=t1){
        t=t0+dt*i;
        y2=C*exp(-t);
        printf("%lf%25lf\n",t,y2);}}

  free(y);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;}

double user_fun_1(double t,double y){
  return t;}
double user_fun_2(double t, double y){
  return -y;}
double rk4(double(*f)(double, double), double dt,double t,double y){
  double k1,k2,k3,k4;
  k1=dt*f(t,y);
  k2=dt*f(t + dt/2,y + k1/2);
  k3=dt*f(t + dt/2,y + k2/2);
  k4=dt*f(t + dt,y + k3);
  return y + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 +k4)/6;}
```

Comment: this line: if (funct=1){ and this line if (funct=2) are both incorrect;  they are assigning 1 or 2 to the funct variable. the correct syntax is: if( 1 == funct ){ and if(2 == funct ){  Note: this is the main reason to place the literal on the left, so the compiler catches these kinds of coding errors, so we dont have to spend our time debugging your code.

Comment: when writing printf format parameter strings, there should be a space between most parameters, especially successive strings or successive numbers, so the displayed result is easily read due to a space between the parameter outputs

Comment: lines like this: y[i]=rk4(user_fun_2,dt,t0+dt*(i-1),y[i-1]); are not a valid call to the rk4() function because the user_fun_2() needs two double parameters.  If all the warnings were enabled for your compiler, it would have told you about this problem where user_fun_2() is being called with the wrong number of parameters..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` statement is wrong, it is an assignment not a comparison.  It should be

```
if (funct==2)
```

NOT

```
if (funct=2)
```

The same goes to the first `if` statement.

A a safe c habit is to swap places of the constant and variable in an if statement. if(2==funtc) works and if(2=funct) will give a compile time error. 
Try to turn on compiler warning next time, it can help you find this type of error.  If you are using `gcc`, add `-Wall -Wextra` flags.

The reason your `t, y` is longer than `t, y exact` is your `n =101`, and `t1 = 10`.
So in first `for` loop, you wrote `i++`, so it loops for 100 times, but in the second `for` loop, you use `i+=t1`, so it only loops for 11 times.

The reason `t` is always 0, is because you never assign any initial value to it nor assign a value in the first `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you!  Would you happen to know why my columns for t,y are have all 0s for t and are much longer than the t,y2 columns?

Comment: @Mike Can you provide some sample input in your question, so ppl can duplicate your results?

Comment: @Mike I have update my answer according to your input.  Hope it helps.

Comment: And this is why I wish GCC would [enable `-Wall` by default](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-04/msg00087.html).

Comment: Personally, I hate reading code with inverted comparisons; I prefer to write the variable that I'm comparing on the the left and the value I'm comparing it with on the right.  Since there are compiler options to generate the warning, I use them all the time, so I don't run into this problem for long — the first compilation with the error fails (I use `-Werror` too).